# Java чтение данных с порта в протоколе CAN

Tags: java, can

Хочу написать на Java приложение для чтения данных в протоколе CAN.

Сразу скажу, что я в курсе, что Java для этого не лучший вариант, но задача не очень большая и изучать Си не очень хочется, может все-таки есть возможность реализовать это на Java.

Посмотрел что есть в Java из библиотек и нашел только поддержку OpenCan и CAN для сименовских контроллеров. Я получаю данные в чистом CAN.
Подскажите какие тут можно использовать библиотеки или функции для чтения данных.
Или поделитесь ссылкой на готовое решение или хотя бы на пример, как это можно реализовать на Java.
Буду рад любой информации

Желательно OS Windows, но если там совсем все плохо то можно как вариант и Linux рассмотреть.
В качестве адаптера планировал использовать Марафон, CAN-USB.

Comment: я добавил в вопрос информацию

Comment: У марафона SDK на C/C++ . Получается в этом случае только C/C++? Подключение по USB.